# Vehicle Routing with container compatibility

Tags: algorithm, routes, containers, compatibility

I am currently working on an algorithm for the special type of the routing problem. The problem looks as follows. Given is:
-a set of containers with n different types
-a set of trucks with k different types
-a graph where each node represents a customer that needs to be visited, where all nodes are connected with cost function which represents time distances

Further, we have following constraints:
-matrix which represents compatibility between truck and container types (for example, truck type t1 can only carry containers of types c1, c3, c5... t2 can carry only c4, c5, c7 and so on)
-matrix which represents compatibility between customers and orders (Customer s1 has equipment to work only with containers of type c2, c5, c6...)
-trucks can come to terminal and change containers if needed

The goal is to visit all customers in minimum amount of time.

Do you know any similar problem in the literature? What do you think that would be the best approach to solve this?

Any help is appreciated.